# how to pass position of list item clicked using intent and use that data in my switch case function which shown in code

Tags: android

list view item click and passing position using intent

```
ListView lstview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lstview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
    lstview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Bundle basket=new Bundle();
            basket.getInt("pos",position);
            Intent a= new Intent(Customlist.this,Customgrid.class);
            a.putExtras(basket);
            startActivity(a);


        }
    });
```

getting bundle data from previous activity and using  in switch block which is implemented inside getview method but it's not working properly..plz help..

```
public class Customgrid extends Activity {

public Integer gotbread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customgview);
    Bundle gotbasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    gotbread = gotbasket.getInt("pos");
    GridView grdview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    grdview.setAdapter(new Customgridadapter(this));
    grdview.setVerticalSpacing(5);
}

public class Customgridadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public Integer[] images1 = { R.drawable.s_1, R.drawable.s_2,
            R.drawable.s_3 };
    public Integer[] images2 = { R.drawable.s_5, R.drawable.s_6,
            R.drawable.s_4 };
    Context m1Context;

    public Customgridadapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.m1Context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return images1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) m1Context)
                .getLayoutInflater();
        View customRow1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gview, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) customRow1
                .findViewById(R.id.imageforgrid);
       switch (gotbread) {
        case 0:
            image.setImageResource(images2[position]);
            break;
        case 1:
            image.setImageResource(images1[position]);
            break;
        }
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setScaleX((float) 0.5);
        image.setScaleY((float) 0.5);
        return customRow1;
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OnItemClickListener` it should be

```
basket.putInt("pos",position);
```

not

```
basket.getInt("pos",position);
```